# Do I have to rewrite package directory one by one when I change directory of java file on vim?

Tags: java, vim

These days, I am practicing myself to develop Java(Spring Boot) using Vim.
And I just wonder if I have to rewrite package directory in Java file one by one when I change it.
For example, in Java file we should write package directory on top of the file like below.

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

public class TestController {
...
}
```

I am wondering if there is any way to change the file contents synchronously when I change the directory of file in Vim.
Thank you in advance.

When I changed the directory of file by m + m(move the current node), I realized in the package directory in the file and also in files which imported that file, the directory has changed.

Comment: `I am wondering if there is any way to change the file contents synchronously when I change the directory of file in Vim.` Java requires that the "directory" of a file match the package name in most cases.  If a class `MyClass` is in `package com.example;` then the directory structure has to be `com/example/MyClass.java`.  Anything else will break most of the tools that ship with the JDK.  I assume that with enough work you could go around that but I also assume it won't be worth the effort.

Comment: @markspace Thanks for the comment. I used to use Intellij and other IDE and when I changed the file name or directory, I remember that IDE always asked me back if I want to change following file contents itself and others which import that file. That was why I had this question. I found that Vi is really useful except for this question.

Comment: I don't use Vim. But my guess is you'd probably have to find some extensions that provide refactoring support for Java. I have no idea if such extensions exist.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason to use an IDE and not a text editor.  I used vi a lot back in the day but modern IDEs are just so much more productive with features a text editor can't match that it's no longer even a contest.  IDEs are always better.

Comment: @Slaw Yes that is why I wrote this question. I hope there really is.

Comment: @markspace I see. That is sad. 
I just wanted to understand some hardcore developers who still using Vim to develop. And I found myself that once I used to IDE, without IDE I cannot even run jar file in terminal.

Comment: Vim is a general purpose text editor that happens to provide minimal-to-quite-good support for hundreds of programming languages but it still is a text editor. It has never been, is not, and will never be a convincing alternative for those who need or desire the full power of an IDE. If you don't need or desire all that power, then Vim is amazing, but if you do—and you appear to do—then there is no point even contemplating a switch. Just use the best tool for the job.

Comment: Right, using the best tool is a thing.  I keep up on vi in case I have to do some quick edits on a Unix command line.  But most of the time I use a full IDE to do my work.  And I think I could edit a Java file, compile it and run it on the command line, but if I forget then I just look up how to do it on the web.  Google is your friend.  It doesn't happen frequently enough to be something I actually need to know how to do.

Comment: @markspace Alright. Thanks for those comments and have a great day :)

Comment: @romainl Alright. Thanks! Good day.